# cmake and make in Windows

Tags: visual-studio-2010, cmake

I understand that in linux cmake, make and make install can be combined together to produce a release. For example:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make
make install
```

In windows, however, I cannot find similar commands that can do the same job. Usually, what is done is to build a .sln project first if Visual Studio is used, after that compile the .sln project and in the end run the INSTALL project. Will it be possible to make a release with several commands as it has been done in Linux. Many thanks.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use msbuild instead of make:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 12" ..
msbuild /P:Configuration=Release INSTALL.vcxproj
```

or you could use CMake's [`--build`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/git-master/manual/cmake.1.html) argument:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 12" ..
cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config Release
```

If you need the equivalent of the `make` command with no args (i.e. `make all`) you would build the `ALL_BUILD` target as well, but this is built as part of the `INSTALL` target anyway.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to me that the second solution works.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [Fraser's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387504/cmake-and-make-in-windows#answer-21387766), to get the first solution to work, one might need to call MSBuild in CMD as Administrator from the original path

```
cmake ..
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\YEAR\EDITION\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" INSTALL.vcxproj -p:Configuration=Release
```

*Replace `YEAR` and `EDITION` with your corresponding values e.g. 2017 and Community*

You might receive the following error, which means your enviroment variable is not set.

> error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. 
>   Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists 
>   on disk.

The enviroment variable can be set directly in the system settings or with CMD as Administrator. [(Source for reference)](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cbdd99d7-2bfb-4376-9eae-7ede22a50d37/microsoftcppdefaultprops-not-in-correct-folder-help-needed?forum=visualstudiogeneral)

for **Visual Studio 2015** and below:

```
SET VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\vXXX\"
```

*Replace `vXXX` with your corresponding version e.g. 140*

for **Visual Studio 2017** and above:

```
SET VCTargetsPath="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\YEAR\EDITION\Common7\IDE\VC\VCTargets\"
```

*Replace `YEAR` and `EDITION` with your corresponding values e.g. 2017 and Community*

---

**Edit:**

I've also noticed that some solutions in Visual Studio 2017 wont show their contents in the Solution Explorer if the enviroment variable is set. Just remove them again if necessary.