# how to use make and make install in mac

Tags: c++, macos, cmake

I have a question related to  [cmake and make in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21387504/cmake-and-make-in-windows). As we already knows that in windows we can use

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 12" ..
cmake --build . --target INSTALL --config Release
```

to compile and install the target using command lines. In linux, we can use

```
cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ..
make
make install
```

to do the same job. Then how about mac? In mac, I tried to use:

```
cmake -DCMAKE_OSX_ARCHITECTURES=x86_64 ../ -G Xcode
make
make install
```

but failed. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [cmake --build](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.12/cmake.html#opt%3a--builddir) on any platform as it

> abstracts a native build tool's command-line interface

Comment: cmake --build ./ --target install